# How can I increase the number of inodes in an ext4 filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, files, partition, size, inode

I had a problem (new to me) last week. I have a ext4 (Fedora 15) filesystem. The application that runs on the server suddenly stopped. I couldn't find the problem at first look.

`df` showed 50% available space. After searching for about an hour I saw a forum post where the guy used `df -i`. The option looks for inodes usage. The system was out of inodes, a simple problem that I didn't realize. The partition had only 3.2M inodes.

Now, my questions are: Can I make the system have more inodes? Should/can it be set when formatting the disk? With the 3.2M inodes, how many files could I have?

Comment: Every file or directory uses one inode.  A hard link to a file does *not* create an inode.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397110/how-to-store-one-billion-files-on-ext4 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618820/how-many-bytes-per-inodes?rq=1

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It seems that you have a lot more files than normal expectation.

I don't know whether there is a solution to change the inode table size dynamically.  I'm afraid that you need to back-up your data, and create new filesystem, and restore your data.

To create new filesystem with such a huge inode table, you need to use '-N' option of mke2fs(8).

I'd recommend to use '-n' option first (which does not create the fs, but display the use-ful information) so that you could get the estimated number of inodes.  Then if you need to, use '-N' to create your filesystem with a specific inode numbers.

Comment: You can use `mke2fs -i` to specify the number of inodes. Its documentation indicates that “it is not possible to expand the number of inodes on a filesystem after it is created”.

Comment: Can't change the number of inodes, but we can change the size (which is quite useless) [tune2fs](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/8893/). Your answers were helpful, but the question now is what's the relation between inodes and total number of files?

Comment: @piovisqui: each file consume on inode, which is a pointer in the filesystem. if the file is an hard-link to another file it has the same inode.

Comment: @Gilles The `-i` options specifies the size of the inode, not how many there are. The `-N` option sets the number inodes.

Comment: The relation between inodes and file numbers isn't necessarily 1:1. The first inode contains a list of pointers to blocks where the file is stored. If the list of blocks can't fit within one inode, then the inode contains a list of pointers to inodes which list the blocks where the file is stored. If it doesn't fit there then it goes 3 sets of inodes deep for that list of blocks etc.

Comment: @StuWhitby That's not quite right. A single inode has several direct pointers, and a single, double, and triple indirect pointer. If the list of blocks can't fit in the direct pointers, then the single indirect pointer will point at a block of data (NOT another inode) that contains more pointers. If more pointers than that are needed, the double indirect pointer points at a block that contains single indirect pointers, and the triple indirect at a block with double indirect pointers. So a file does, in fact, just use one inode, regardless of size.

Answer (score 22):

With 3.2 million inodes, you can have 3.2 million files and directories, total (but multiple hardlinks to a file only use one inode).

Yes, it can be set when creating a filesystem on the partition. The options `-T usage-type`, `-N number-of-inodes`, or `-i bytes-per-inode` can all set the number of inodes. I generally use `-i`, after comparing the output of `du -s` and `find | wc -l` for a similar collection of files and allowing for some slack.

No, it can't be changed in-place on an existing filesystem.  However:

- If you're running LVM or the filesystem is on a SAN's LUN (either directly on the LUN, or as the last partition on the LUN), or you have empty space on the disk after the partition, you can grow the partition and then use `resize2fs` to expand the filesystem. This adds more inodes in proportion to the added space, roughly. If you want to avoid running out of inodes before space assuming that future files on average have about the same size, set a high enough reserved block percentage using `tune2fs -m`.
- If you have enough space and can take the filesystem offline, then take it offline, create a new filesystem with more inodes, and copy all the files over.
- If just a subset of the files are using a lot of the inodes and you have enough free space, create a filesystem on a loop device backed by a file on the filesystem, create a filesystem with more inodes (and maybe smaller blocks as well) on it, and move the offending directories into it.  That's probably a performance hit and a maintenance hassle, but it is an alternative.
- And of course, if you can delete a lot of unneeded files, that should help too.

Answer (score 18):

As another workaround I could suggest considering packing huge collections of files into an uncompressed(!) `tar` archive, and then using `archivemount` to mount it as a filesystem. A tar archive is better for sharing than a filesystem image and provides similar performance when backing up to a cloud or another storage.

---

If the collection is supposed to be read-only, `squashfs` may be an option, but it requires certain options enabled in the kernel, and `xz` compression is available for tar as well with the same performance.

Comment: Nice suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

I have an alternate solutions for this situation. Lets say you have 1000 inodes in a **partition** of 10G. But due to inodes limit you are not suppose to use all space of **partition**. But in this solutions you will be able to use the remaining space of the **partition** without **formatting** it.

```
$ df -i  # see list ( I need just one free inode here so move just one file into other PARTITION)
/dev/part1  1000 999 1 99.9%     /data

$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/new_data
$ mkfs.ext4 /data/new_data
$ mkdir /data1
$ mount /data/new_data /data1
```

**for permanent mounting**

```
$ echo "/data/new_data /data1 ext4 defaults 0 1" >> /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. I took the liberty to reformat your answer to the more usual representation of code here, inserting a prompt (`$`) to clearly distinguishing between commands and output (if they were only command, the prompt is normally left out). I also changed the SHOUTING in the bold phase emphasis, which is what I think you intended. You can roll back the changes if I misrepresented things

Comment: I think this solution has logic, but you need to manage the size when running dd.

Comment: The details are  wrong, you'd need to use a loop device, and maybe even unionfs depending on the application, but this is the only solution avoiding formatting and restoring from backup which is no fun when in a hurry with millions of files. There are circumstances where this could save the day !

Answer (score 8):

try `du -s --inodes * 2>/dev/null |sort -g` the cd into the last dir in output and repeat.

Full Disclosure: not all OS's support `--inodes` flag for du command (my Mac OS does not) but many Linux OS's do.

Answer (score 6):

Recently ran into this issue when using apt or aptitude upgrade.

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  5.1G  2.3G  70% /

df -i

Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     524288 521497   2791  100% /
```

Issued command:

```
du /|sort -k1 -n
```

Revealed most of files were in subfolders for several kernel versions within:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers
```

Removed those subfolders and inode problem was fixed.

```
df -i

Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     524288 104986 419302   21% /
```

Comment: does "du /|sort -k1 -n" show inodes?

Comment: No. That was to sort the directories, showing which ones had the most files in them, folders which were consuming lots of inodes but less actual space usage: the situation of 30% free disk space yet 100% inode usage shown above.

Comment: I honestly dont get how "du" shown how many files there are with any flag? Could you please explain more in detail?

Comment: No flags for the `du` command. Usage is for the root of file-system in above example, looking at space only. Output is piped to sort in order to show which directories contained the most files. There isn't a count done in above example for files, the 'how many files' portion of your question. Kernel source ones were the culprit shown in the `du` output though; e.g., many small files, sub-folders from past compilations, the very thing ideally suited for removal in order to free up inodes. There still remains a manual, human review of the `du` output, `/usr/src/linux-headers` was then obvious.

Comment: du shows ONLY bytes - not files. And you are piping the outout only from the du command into sort. So how does sort -k1 -n sort the output in that way you proposed? The only thing I can see is that "du /|sort -k1 -n" only sort every row based on the size in bytes. Nothing else

Comment: Was helpful for me, seeing directories which shouldn't normally have such size usage shown. It produced the listing revealing the /usr/src/linux-headers. Your system, experience may vary. If you need an individual file count by folder, summary for the filesystem can use gawk; I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Alright, so I can basicly type du -h / | sort -k1 -n and get the same output but more readable. So it does'nt really show inodes, just size in bytes.

Comment: This advice was really helpful.  I ran out of inodes on a virtual machine, and clearing out `/usr/src` got me back like 800,000 inodes (on a system with about a million of them).