# What is the fastest way to create a list of directories specified in a file?

Tags: mkdir

I have a text file, "foo.txt", that specifies a directory in each line:

```
data/bar/foo
data/bar/foo/chum
data/bar/chum/foo
...
```

There could be millions of directories and subdirectories
What is the quickest way to create all the directories in bulk, using a terminal command ?

By quickest, I mean quickest to create all the directories. Since there are millions of directories there are many write operations.

I am using ubuntu 12.04.

EDIT: Keep in mind, the list may not fit in memory, since there are MILLIONS of lines, each representing a directory.

EDIT: My file has 4.5 million lines, each representing a directory, composed of alphanumeric characters, the path separator "/" , and possibly "../"

When I ran `xargs -d '\n' mkdir -p < foo.txt` after a while it kept printing errors until i did ctrl + c:

mkdir: cannot create directory `../myData/data/a/m/e/d': No space left on device

But running `df -h` gives the following output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda        48G   20G   28G  42% /
devtmpfs        2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
none            401M  164K  401M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
```

free -m

```
 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4002       3743        258          0       2870         13
-/+ buffers/cache:        859       3143
Swap:          255         26        229
```

EDIT:
df -i

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda      2872640 1878464 994176   66% /
devtmpfs        512053    1388 510665    1% /dev
none            512347     775 511572    1% /run
none            512347       1 512346    1% /run/lock
none            512347       1 512346    1% /run/shm
```

df -T

```
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda      ext4      49315312 11447636  37350680  24% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs   2048212        4   2048208   1% /dev
none           tmpfs       409880      164    409716   1% /run
none           tmpfs         5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      2049388        0   2049388   0% /run/shm
```

EDIT: I increased the number of inodes, and reduced the depth of my directories, and it seemed to work. It took 2m16seconds this time round.

Comment: Is this a virtual machine? Does the main node has enough space?

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26600/88378) can help you with the inodes problem. You will need to nuke the current filesystem on that partition, but if that's a virtual filesytem running inside a regular file that shouldn't be a major issue.

Comment: Yes. You seem to have enough space in all the partitions, there are free inodes, but still if it says you don't have enough space, probably the hypervisor on which your VPS is located has run out of space. You might have to contact your VPS provider to check that.

Comment: Is that output from `df -i` from before or after you try to run `xargs -d '\n' mkdir -p < foo.txt` ?

Comment: What FS type (`df -T /`)?

Comment: @John, then I don't know. AFAIK, there's no limit on ext4 on the number of entries in a directory (or it's very high). It would make sense to ask a separate question for your "no space left" issue. Can you not create directories at all now, or only in specific directories?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I ignored the problem, and just increased the size of the disk image so that there are more inodes. I also reduced the depth of the directory structure and it seems to work. So now I could run your command without problem :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With GNU `xargs`:

```
xargs -d '\n' mkdir -p -- < foo.txt
```

`xargs` will run as few `mkdir` commands as possible.

With standard syntax:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
 sed 's/[[:blank:]"\'\'']/\\&/g' < foo.txt | xargs mkdir -p --)
```

Where it's not efficient is that `mkdir -p a/b/c` will attempt some `mkdir("a")` and possibly `stat("a")` and `chdir("a")` and same for `"a/b"` even if `"a/b"` existed beforehand.

If your `foo.txt` has:

```
a
a/b
a/b/c
```

in that order, that is, if for each path, there have been a line for each of the path components before, then you can omit the `-p` and it will be significantly more efficient. Or alternatively:

```
perl -lne 'mkdir $_ or warn "$_: $!\n"' < foo.txt
```

Which avoids invoking a (many) `mkdir` command altogether.

Comment: In your standard syntax, does it mean POSIX?

Comment: My file has millions of lines, will it really be able to pass them all as arguments ?

Comment: @John, `xargs` runs as many instances of the command as needed so as to avoid the limit on the maximum number of arguments. So it will probably invoke many `mkdir` commands each one of them passed a few thousand of directories to create.

Comment: It repeats the error "mkdir: cannot create directory `../myData/data/a/m/e/d': No space left on device" many times for each file ? Could there be a bug in your command ? My file seems to have only unique entries. Or is this just how the error is displayed ?

Comment: @KaizerSozay, you're running out of space or inodes, the errors are probably about creating a directory component _leading_ to the files.

Answer (score 1):

I know we will get lot of answers for this question.But still you can **TRY** this **:) :D**

`while read -r line; do mkdir -p "$line" ; done < file.txt`

Comment: That's running one mkdir per directory and is flawed because of that wrong usage of `read` and the split+glob operator.

Comment: Yes it is.Because of dependency.To create the folder bar we should have data and in the same way for others.But I didn't find any flaws in `read`.Can you execute my command and check it once?.I did and it's working for me.

Comment: To read a line, it's `IFS= read -r line`, `read line` does extra processing. Leaving `$line` unquoted means invoking the split+glob operator. `mkdir` can take several arguments.

Comment: Oh k.Thank you.I will improve my answer. I just took the above example ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one-liner:

`for i in $(cat foo.txt) ; do mkdir -p $i ; done`

This will create the directory/directory-tree in the current working directory. Not in bulk (as in all-the-directories-getting-created-simulataneously), but the creation will be done one after another.

Comment: That's running one mkdir per directory and is flawed because of that wrong usage of the split+glob operator. That also means storing that whole huge list in memory.

Comment: Cool. Going through the `man` page of `xargs` now after looking at your comment in the question. Always something new to learn everytime I open SE :)

Comment: What about $i? Unquoted?? :P

Comment: But how is it holding a hugelist in memory since there is only one iteration variable. Wouldn't it hold only that one variable during each iteration?

Comment: @Sree, expanding `$(cat...)` means reading the output of `cat` in memory, split+glob it and iterate over the resulting huge list.

Comment: To be honest, since we don't know the entire list of directories, we cannot assume that this answer is correct. A single space in a name will cause the wrong directory structure to be built.

Comment: there are no spaces. the directory paths are only alpha numeric characters, "../"  and the path separator "/"

Comment: @KaizerSozay I know this is old but - the point is that the file *could* have spaces; and if you're saying that files can't have spaces in them you're wrong (so can directories but directories are a file in the end). They can also have newlines (etc.).