# How to increase inode size in Debian

Tags: debian, inode

I have VPS of following configuration.

```
RAM : 4GB
Swapped RAM : 4GB
Disk : 500GB
```

I'm unable to start any service it's showing No Space is available.

```
df -i

Filesystem                                              Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
rootfs                                                 6545408 6544345   1063  100% /
udev                                                    510093     297 509796    1% /dev
tmpfs                                                   514106     225 513881    1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4bdbc1bc-2c9d-48d9-a6ab-654bc6ca727a 6545408 6544345   1063  100% /
tmpfs                                                   514106       2 514104    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   514106       2 514104    1% /run/shm
/dev/xvda1                                               62248      20  62228    1% /boot
```

Is there anyway to increase inode value by means of swapping or anything? I've enough disk space but 100% inode value giving me this problem.

Comment: what does `df -h /` say? if you're sure you have enough free space, take a look at tune2fs : [link](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs)

Comment: What is the file system? If it's ext2/3/4 you have to [recreate it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26598/12779) specifying more inodes. Some other file systems offer dynamic inodes.

Comment: i've ext3 type partitioned disk. it's provided by vps provider. without recreate how can i increase inode value.?

Comment: As I mentioned above, you cannot.

Comment: df -h shows 37% of tatal disk being used. Now itself df -i is 100%, then is rest of disk is unusable..?