# Tab completion errors: bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Tags: debian, shell, ssh, tmp

When using the tab bar, I keep getting this error:

> bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device"

Any ideas?

I have been doing some research, and many people talk about the /tmp file, which might be having some overflow. When I execute `df -h` I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sda2       9.1G  8.7G     0 100% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           618M  8.8M  609M   2% /run
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  132K  511M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda4       1.8T  623G  1.1T  37% /home
tmpfs           309M  4.0K  309M   1% /run/user/116
tmpfs           309M     0  309M   0% /run/user/1000
```

It looks like the /dev/data directory is about to explode, however if I tip:

```
$ du -sh /dev/sda2
0   /dev/sda2
```

It seems it's empty.

I am new in Debian and I really don't know how to proceed. I used to typically access this computer via ssh. Besides this problem I have several others with this computer, they might be related, for instance each time I want to enter my user using the GUI (with root it works) I get:

> Xsession: warning: unable to write to /tmp: Xsession may exit with an error

Comment: You want to run something like `du -hxd1 /`, not `du /dev/sda2`. `/dev/sda2` doesn't really exist on disk.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your root file system is full and hence your temp dir (/tmp, and /var/tmp for that matter) are also full. A lot of scripts and programs require some space for working files, even lock files. When /tmp is unwriteable *bad* things happen.

You need to work out how you've filled the filesystem up. Typically places this will happen is in /var/log (check that you're cycling the log files). Or /tmp may be full. There's many, many other ways that a disk can fill up, however.

```
du -hs /tmp /var/log
```

You may wish to re-partition to give /tmp it's own partition (that's the old school way of doing it, but if you have plenty of disk it's fine), or map it into memory (which will make it very fast but start to cause swapping issues if you overdo the temporary files).

Comment: Hi, I looked at both commands that you suggest and I would say that both /tmp and /var/log are quite empty: 60K and 49M respectively.

Comment: Hi again. I finally got it. I don't know why did I place all the owncloud content under /var. It works again!

Comment: For anyone using `ncdu` to track down what's taking up space, try running it with `sudo`. It didn't show me the true size of /var/log until I ran it with sudo because /var/log/httpd was owned by `root:root`.

Comment: the `du -hs /tmp /var/log` command needs to be executed as super user (sudo) to avoid "Permission denied" errors while reading the aforementioned directories' content

Answer (score 55):

If anyone gets here with this error when their disk isn't full, be sure to check not just `df` but also `df -i`. There are a fixed number of inodes on a filesystem, and every file needs one. If you have just tons of small files, it's very easy for your filesystem to fill up with these small files while there's still plenty of space left on the drive when you run `df`.

Comment: This was the problem I had! I kept trying to find what was occupying space. That wasn't the problem at all.
 I had fully used up the inodes.
`/dev/root      4980000 4980000      0  100% /`
Maybe the system should respond with an appropriate error message?

Comment: Same for me, Plesk server with nginx sometimes crashing and sometimes working, couldn't work out what was wrong until one of our techs got this error on the command line. The number of nodes rather then the space was the issue as identified by df -i. Thanks

Comment: What am I supposed to do to solve this issue?

Comment: @ShahriarRahmanZahin if you have too many files, you'll have to get rid of some. move important stuff elsewhere, delete unneeded old logs or similar. if it's your software, maybe change it to use fewer files ( use an sqlite db instead of filesystem as db perhaps? ), you could use a cron job to purge old unneeded logs and make sure temp files aren't left sitting around. if you control the filesystem, backup and recreate with more inodes available perhaps? I can't give specific answers as I don't know your situation. good luck.

Comment: @ShahriarRahmanZahin re: increasing inodes https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem

Answer (score 26):

You may also have lost write access to the `/tmp/` directory.

It should look like that:

```
ls -l / |grep tmp
drwxrwxrwt   7 root root  4096 Nov  7 17:17 tmp
```

You can fix the permissions like that:

```
chmod a+rwxt /tmp
```

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: That's a useless use of grep. Try `ls -ld /tmp` instead.

Comment: you just halted a near full on panic attack...worth a vote up for me

Answer (score 13):

The fastest way to locate your folders that are too full is by narrowing down the folder file size in levels from the root folder.
You start with the root folder by:

```
sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /
```

Then - EITHER you increase the depth, i.e. the levels below:

```
sudo du -h --max-depth=2 /
```

OR - quicker - you you look which folder has eaten up the most disk space, and do the same on this folder:

```
sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /home/<user>/<overfull-folder>
```

Once you found it, just remove that one:

```
rm -rf <path to overfull-folder>
```

Comment: with many output files it's nice to sort them by size with `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 / | sort -h` (bigger files at the bottom or `sort -hr` for bigger files on top)

Comment: This helped me to solve my problem. I was struggling with some hours with this.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting error, then I saw

```
[  672.995482] EXT4-fs (sda2): Remounting filesystem read-only
[  672.999802] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_journal_check_start:60: Detected aborted journal
```

I was able to confirm this,

```
mount | grep -i sda2
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (ro,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Comment: dmesg | grep read-only -C 10

Answer (score 1):

**If your using Docker:**

Just to help any one using docker, just make sure you are deleting the "left over" images from the building process.

To see which images are currently on disk
 `$ docker images`

It will give you a long list and you can start deleting images that you don't need.

`$ docker rmi <image id>`.

This should restore your system back to normal.

This is what was causing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For my case of this same error, it was a cagefs issue as this server was on CloudLinux, addressed with `cagefsctl --remount username`

Answer (score 0):

People have written many things here.

But, I simply emptied the trash bin. It works fine for me now.

```
 rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

Comment: There is no folder in my machine like the one you mentioned : " taccuser@taccuser-All-Series:~/.local/share$ cd Trash
-bash: cd: Trash: No such file or directory
"

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. In my case, the disk was filled up by `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log` echoing each other in a blizzard of repeated messages, in what was perhaps a kernel panic. 13 G each file. I couldn't delete or resize in place with sed because I couldn't even `sudo` or `su -`. I had to reboot in recovery mode and drop to a root shell to truncate the files, which I did with `sed -i '10001,$ d' /var/log/syslog` and  `sed -i '10001,$ d' /var/log/kern.log` (the repeating messages started before the 10000th line in both files).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a read-only root filesystem.

I was able to get tab-completion working for the time being by mounting a temporary filesystem in /tmp (`sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp`), and reopening `bash` so it could latch onto the new /tmp folder.

Answer (score -1):

Since reboots are very rare on my system , my `/tmp` had piled up a lot of junk ....Faced this problem recently and cleaned up  my `/tmp` folder.

```
cd /tmp
sudo rm -rf *
```

Comment: Unfortunately this neither contails a check whether `/tmp` is the problem nor is a good approach. Only older files should be deleted (without a check whether they are in use yet).

Answer (score -1):

Below thing worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Answer (score -2):

This is because the disk space is not enough, you need to clean up large files or clean up the process that takes up space:

1. `df -h` View hard disk space
2. `du -sh /*` View which directory is the largest, step by step to find large files
3. `du -h --max-depth=1` find the largest file

Comment: This seems to just regurgitate the answer by Agile Bean from June 2018.