# increase the number of inodes online

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

Dears, I have a Redhat linux server `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)`. It's a production sensitive server. now it ran out of inodes in `/storage2` directory. It has many space but it almost finished inodes and I need to increase the number of inodes ASAP. with [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem)  It has the solution but it  needed to have backup and after changing the number of inodes in file system restore them. I wonder if there is any online solution so I could increase the inodes without taking backup and restore.

```
$ df -h 
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02
                       20G  6.5G   12G  35% /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol04
                       58G  4.4G   51G   8% /home
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01
                      9.7G  211M  9.0G   3% /tmp
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol03
                       20G   16G  2.6G  87% /var
/dev/mapper/vg_fvnx_stg2-lv_fvnx_stg2
                      3.0T  2.2T  690G  76% /storage2



$ df -ih 
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02
                        5.0M    270K    4.8M    6% /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol04
                         15M     310     15M    1% /home
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01
                        2.5M      71    2.5M    1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol03
                        5.0M    7.9K    5.0M    1% /var
/dev/mapper/vg_fvnx_stg2-lv_fvnx_stg2
                        192M    191M    1.3M  100% /storage2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer : no, you can't increase the inodes without taking the backup/restore.

man page for [`mkfs.ext4`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4) (which I assume is the filesystem type in play here) is pretty clear on this:

> It is not possible  to change this value after the filesystem is created."

You could look into such solutions as creating a `/storage2/subdirectoryname` filesystem, and effectively place a few thousand files into that new filesystem, thus releasing a pile of inodes from `/storage2`.

Comment: I think that  solution makes no difference, moving  files to a subdirecttory release inodes? I think the inode count is constant in entire filesystem and a subdirectory is not new filesystem

Comment: revised wording to make clear that I propose creating a new filesystem, /storage2/subdirectoryname