# Inode limit reached with free space available

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, ext4, inode

Let's assume I was very unlucky and ran out of inodes in my `ext4` filesystem but left with enough free space.

Inode usage is 100%, but it has 50% disk free space.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem and precisely this comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem#comment35923_26600 . Ratio can't be changed. But growing the filesystem will thus also increase inode capacity. As I guess you want this without growth, I'm just leaving a comment (it's probably a duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to **recreate your filesystem** specifying **bytes-to-inode** ratio with `-i` option.

1. **Backup** all of your data to another disk.
2. List your filesystems and find the one you want to modify:

   `$ df -h`

   assuming that filesystem is `/dev/sdX` and is mounted on `/mnt/mountpoint`.
3. **Unmount** that filesystem:

   `$ umount /mnt/mountpoint`
4. **Create** that filesystem using `mkfs.ext4` command specifying `-i` byte-to-inode ratio:

   `$ mkfs.ext4 -i 4096 /dev/sdX`

   This command will create `ext4` filesystem with 4 KB per inode ratio (which will create four times more inodes than the default value - 16 KB per inode).
5. **Mount** that filesystem:

   `$ mount /dev/sdX /mnt/mountpoint`

Comment: I don't understand the last requirement. What permissions might need to be applied that are only triggered during a reboot?

Comment: When rebooted, it will **mount** the filesystem as indicated in `/etc/fstab` with previous owner, group owner, umask permission, etc.

Comment: You did that already in step 5

Comment: Oh. Got it, thanks!